# Destructuring nested props got undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
    const {
      name
    } = props.users;
    return { name };
  }
}
```

With the above code, I got an error of

```
TypeError
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

*What is the issue? I thought object deconstructing will handle automatically if `users` is undefined?*

Can I use if statement in `getDerivedStateFromProps` and without return anything?

Comment: `props.users` seems to be undefined. Destructuring doesn’t handle that. Consider using `props?.users`?

Comment: `"Destructuring doesn’t handle that"` --> You can still use destructuring with a default value like my[answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66979479/9071943) @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 5):

> "I thought object deconstructing will handle automatically if `users`
> is undefined?"

No, it doesn't do automatically.

In the case of `props.users` seems to be `undefined`, you will get this error

```js
const props = {};
const { user: {name} } = props;
console.log(name); 
// "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined",
```

**Solution:** *Use `Default value` to get rid of that error*

```js
const props = {};
const { user: {name} = {name: "default-user-name"} } = props;
console.log(name);
```

Comment: I thought this is what you meant. 